# PHP & JavaScript: My code is not working after I convert my Static Dropdown List to Dynamic Dropdown List

Tags: javascript, php

Good day, and here I am again asking for your help.

Here's my Static Dropdown Lists:

```html
<li style="margin-left:5px;"><b><?php echo strtoupper("Advanced Education"); ?></b></li>
<li class="divider"></li>
<li style="margin-left:10px;"><b>Doctor of Philosophy (Ph.D.)</b></li>
<li class="divider"></li>
<li id="test1" style="margin-left:15px;" onclick="getCourseID(1,true,'Major in Education Management')"><a>Major in Education Management</a></li>
<li style="margin-left:15px;" onclick="getCourseID(2)"><a>Major in Technology Management</a></li>
<li style="margin-left:15px;" onclick="getCourseID(3)"><a>Major in Community Management</a></li>
```

Note 1:

> Don't mind the rest of the code just focus on the "onclick"

Note 2 On onclick(param1,param2,param3):

- param1 is for courseID
- param2 - boolean
- param3 for Course Name or Major Name

When I select "Major in Education Management" on the dropdown list using this static code. It's working.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bPFd9.png)

But when I convert the code to Dynamic Lists, it's not working anymore.

Legend on $loadGradProgram[][n]:

- 0 - courseID
- 1 - courseCode
- 2 - courseTitle
- 3 - description (none/Major Name)

```js
function getCourseID(getId,varBool,cName){
        var id = getId;
        var getBool = varBool;
        var getName = cName;

        if (getBool==true){
            document.getElementById("getGName").innerHTML = getName;
            document.getElementById("gradProgram").value = id;

        } else{
            document.getElementById("getUName").innerHTML = getName;
            document.getElementById("underGradProgram").value = id;
        }

    }
```

```html
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li style="margin-left:5px;"><b><?php echo strtoupper("Advanced Education"); ?></b></li>
    <?php
        for($i;$i<=count($loadGradProgram)-1;$i++){
            if($getTitle!= $loadGradProgram[$i][2]){
                $getTitle = $loadGradProgram[$i][2];
    ?>
    <?php
                if($loadGradProgram[$i][3]!="none"){ // Course that has no major
    ?>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li style="margin-left:10px;"><b><?php echo $loadGradProgram[$i][2]; ?> (<?php echo $loadGradProgram[$i][1]?>)</b></li>
    <?php
                }
                else{ // Course with Major
    ?>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li style="margin-left:-10px;" onclick="getCourseID(<?php echo $loadGradProgram[$i][0]; ?>,true,<?php echo " Major in ". $loadGradProgram[$i][2] ." ";?>)"><a><b><?php echo $loadGradProgram[$i][2]; ?> (<?php echo $loadGradProgram[$i][1]?>)</b></a></li>
    <?php
                }
            }
            if($loadGradProgram[$i][3]!="none"){
    ?>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li style="margin-left:15px;" onclick="getCourseID(<?php echo $loadGradProgram[$i][0]; ?>,true,<?php echo " Major in ". $loadGradProgram[$i][3] ." ";?>)"><a><?php echo "Major in ". $loadGradProgram[$i][3] ."";?></a></li>
    <?php
            }
        }
    ?>
</ul>
```

This is the output of the Dropdown List:

[Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QyShS.png)

Comment: Check in javascript console, did you get any error? Because as I can see, there is an issue in `onClick` call. when you are passing values, it must be with quote and in your example which is dynamic `Major in ...` is not bind with quotes.

Comment: A quick observation: `for($i;$i<=count($loadGradProgram)-1;$i++)`, $i should be initialised or else `$loadGradProgram[$i][2]` could possibly get to an undefined index (if it's working as expected right now, it'd be rather safe to consider it to be a matter of chance). So, by the standard conventions, the `for` loop should read something like: `for($i=0; $i<count($loadGradProgram); $i++)`

Comment: @KinjalMistry I already delete the "Major in " on my code still not working.

onclick="getCourseID(<?php echo $loadGradProgram[$i][0]; ?>,true,<?php echo $loadGradProgram[$i][2];?>)

Comment: @KinjalMistry I tried to use Alert code and the result is Array(3) then I used this: $test1 = (string)$loadGradProgram[$i][3]; and the result is "Education Management" but still it's not working

"onclick="getCourseID(<?php echo $loadGradProgram[$i][0]; ?>,true,<?php echo $test1;?>)""

Comment: @Mark you removed "Major in " from your code, but still it is string. So try following. May be it will work for your. `onclick="getCourseID('<?php echo $loadGradProgram[$i][0]; ?>',true,'<?php echo $loadGradProgram[$i][2];?>')"`

Comment: @KinjalMistry woah! It works! I tried that also but I noticed the color of the font turned to yellow so I thought that the "<?php" will convert to string... Thanks a lot!